# How To Update Xubuntu 15.10 on External HDD?

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, xubuntu, external-hdd

I have Xubuntu 15.10 installed on my external HDD (Grub is also there). How can I update/upgrade it to 16.04 LTS?

Directly on external HDD? I mean just press the button upgrade (and Grub will again be on external HDD?)? Or I will have to make Live USB/Live DVD and do a clean install again (and lose my apps and settings)?

Any ideas?

Thnx.

DV

Comment: I think it should work, I've never tried it.

Comment: 16.04 has not been released yet.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Never mind. It will be. What then? That's why I ask. ;-)

Comment: Then you will be able to upgrade "in place" a normal way.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04LTS at least thats what i usually do when a new version comes but still you can do an upgrade but i have bad experience with doing upgrades instead of doing a clean install.
do the clean install or simply upgrade from a live USB.

Comment: Thnx. Sounds like a good advice, bit it leaves me a job of installing all the apps all over again? Which is what I would like to avoid if I only could. What worries me is if an upgrade would mess my MBR/UEFI (whatever).

Comment: @DabizivVojsalic yes thats the bad thing of doing clean install, if you do the clean install then you will have to download the apps all over again but still if you choose the upgrade from a live USB it will probably install the Grub in the external HDD or in main HDD(im not sure but you can try doing the upgrade from a USB) so if you want to upgrade without doing the clean install do it from a live USB.   EDIT: still at least if you choose the clean install you will probably wont have to worry about installing drivers ;)

Comment: Ok. Thnx mate! I think I will follow your advice. You're probably right by saying "probably", which is exactly what I want to avoid. I want to play a safe game, after all. I'll wait - possibly - for some new suggestion, if one doesn't come, there it is, I'm going for a clean install!

Comment: @DabizivVojsalic Alright :) good luck!

Comment: Thnx mate. I'll report with the result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue solved!

I have just upgraded Xubuntu 15.10 to Xubuntu 16.04 LTS on my external HDD "in place". Everything worked just fine. The installation process did not mess my MBR/UEFI, the GRUB stayed where it was - on external HDD.

So, it is sufficient just to start upgrade process in "normal" way, despite the fact is is all about an external HDD.

Cheers folks.

DV